# Install a service handler for URI scheme from webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gmail, uri, uri-scheme

When accessing Google Mail or Google Calendar from Chrome, small icon appears in addressbar allowing to install custom service handler for URI scheme (marked with red square in picture).

[image: Icon for installing custom service handler]

Tooltip for icon is: `This page wants to install a service handler`. When I click icon and allow Google Mail to handle `mailto:` links, all `mailto:` links are opening in Chrome.

Is it possible to create webpage that will be able to install custom handler for my custom URI scheme just like Google Mail do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Chrome (13+), Firefox (3.0+) and Opera (11.60+) it is possible to register web application as service handler for custom URI scheme using JavaScript API:

```
window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler(protocol, uri, title);
```

- `protocol` is the protocol the site wishes to handle, specified as a string.
- `uri` is the URI to the handler as a string. You can include "%s" to indicate where to insert the escaped URI of the document to be handled.
- `title` is the title of the handler presented to the user as a string.

Specifically for Chrome there is a limitation that does not allow to use custom schemes that don't start with `web+` prefix (except standard ones: `mailto`, `mms`, `nntp`, `rtsp` and `webcal`). So if you want to register your web app as service handler as GMail do, you should write something like this:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto", "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s", "Example Mail");
```

or

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("web+myscheme", "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s", "My Cool App");
```

Pay attention at URI pattern, it have to contain `%s` which will be replaced with actual URI of the link user clicks. For example:

```
<a href="web+myscheme:some+data">Open in "My Cool App"</a>
```

will trigger `GET` request to `http://www.example.com/?uri=web%2Bmyscheme%3Asome%20data`

Here are some useful links:

- Standard http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#custom-handlers
- MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/navigator.registerProtocolHandler
- HTML5ROCKS http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler

Comment: That is very useful.